# Are there email addresses ending in ".con"?

Tags: user-input, email-formats

I've noticed that there are a lot of users that misspell their email addresses when registering. For example, if the email is `example@gmail.com`, the user may write `example@gmail.con`. In a registering process, this may lead to the user registering wrong without him/her being aware of.

Is it a good idea to implement a function that changes `.con` for `.com`? This would be a problem if `.con` email addresses exist because they wouldn't be able to register. Do `.con` email addresses exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.con` emails cannot exist (right now) because there is not a top-level domain (TLD) named `.con`

If you go to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#C) or [tld-list.com](https://tld-list.com/tlds-from-a-z), you'll see that there isn't a `.con`

- .computer
- .condos
- .construction
- .consulting
- .contact
- .contractors
- .cooking

No `.con` to be found.

You should probably popup a warning instead of automatically fixing it, though, so that clients are conscious that they made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, there is no `.con` top-level domain (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#C ).

Is it a good idea? That's more of a Product question than a technical question :) Maybe just prevent the user from entering such an address using client-side validation instead of replacing it for them automatically?